# Zooming the separated buttons together

Tags: flutter, dart

when I add a textbutton next to the button in my application, it separates by itself. Like in the photo. How can I zoom plugins?

[image]

```
LikeAnimation(
  isAnimating: (snap.data()! as dynamic)['likes']
      .contains(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid),
  smallLike: true,
  child: IconButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      await FirestoreMethods().LikePost(
        (snap.data()!
            as dynamic)['postId'],
        FirebaseAuth
            .instance.currentUser!.uid,
        (snap.data()!
            as dynamic)['likes'],
      );
    },
    icon: (snap.data()!
                as dynamic)['likes']
            .contains(FirebaseAuth
                .instance
                .currentUser!
                .uid)
        ? const Icon(
            Icons.favorite,
            color: Colors.red,
          )
        : const Icon(
            Icons.favorite_border,
          ),
  ),
),
Container(
  child: DefaultTextStyle(
    style: Theme.of(context)
        .textTheme
        .subtitle2!
        .copyWith(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
        ),
    child: TextButton(
      onPressed: () =>
          Navigator.of(context)
              .push(MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) =>
            LikeScreen(
          snap: (snapshot.data!
                  as dynamic)
              .docs[index],
        ),
      )),
      child: Text(
        '${(snap.data()! as dynamic)['likes'].length}',
        style: Theme.of(context)
            .textTheme
            .bodyText2,
      ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `InkWell` instead of `textbutton`, like this:

```
Row(
          children: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {},
              child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Text('1'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to provide padding.

```dart
TextButton(
style: ButtonStyle(
  padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.zero),
),
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: Can you simplify the widget that will reproduce the issue

Comment: I'm sorry I did not understand

Comment: You can create a sample widget that will provide the same issue [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I made an inkwell and it worked thank you